Using Spotify API in Android Application
I'm following this tutorial to use Spotify inside of my application: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/tutorials/getting-started#authorize-your-application
To add the App Remote SDK I had to follow this tutorial: https://rommansabbir.com/import-aarjar-in-android-studio#heading-new-approach-100-working because the options in New > Module aren't the same as what the Spotify tutorial uses. This is what it looks like now:
1
When adding the dependencies to MainActivity.kt, I'm getting an error "Unresolved reference: spotify". I assume this is because I don't have the aar file set up correctly but I'm not sure how to fix it. I followed those two tutorials (up until the dependencies portion) to a tee. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to fix/correctly implement this? Thanks!
I tried first just the spotify tutorial, but soon found out that I didn't have the option to import a JAR/AAR package in AndroidStudio so I found the tutorial that I followed. I then asked GenAI why it wasn't working but to no avail.
Steps I took for adding Spotify API + code snippets:
First I added a new directory entitled 'spotify-app-remote' into my project's "app" folder. Inside of 'spotify-app-remote', I have 2 files:
File 1: build.gradle:
configurations.maybeCreate("default")

artifacts.add("default", file('[spotify-app-remote-release-0.8.0].aar'))

File 2: the Spotify AAR file
Then, I added this statement into app > settings.gradle.kts:
include(":spotify-app-remote")
Then, I added this statement into app > src > build.gradle.kts:
implementation(project(":spotify-app-remote", configuration = "default"))
These steps should've worked according to the second website I provided, but when I try any of the import statements given by spotify,
(ex: import com.spotify.android.appremote.api.ConnectionParams)
i'm getting an error over "spotify" saying "Unresolved reference: Spotify".

Did you follow the tutorial from Spotify to import the SDK? https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/tutorials/getting-started#add-the-app-remote-sdk

@eten I wasn't able to, those options are no longer available in AndroidStudio. There is an "Import" option but it's only for Eclipse/Gradle projects, not AAR

@eten I added an image to the post of what the new options look like

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I found a resource that does a nice walkthrough on how to do this:
https://tantainnovatives.com/blog/how-to-guides-and-tutorials/integrating-spotify-in-android-apps-a-developers-guide-to-the-spotify-web-api-and-sdk
Followed it up until the end of the "Add the Spotify SDK to Your App" and the imports work now.
